# Woocommerce:Intercept and Redirect on Add to Cart

Tags: woocommerce

The Scenario is i am working with Fancy Product Designers and Woocommerce and I need to Intercept the add_to_cart button send the user to a custom page and change the amount of a certain view just like here on https://www.paperlesspost.com/ is it possible. I've looked at a lot of options no luck so far help a brother out

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a user after adding an item to cart via the [`woocommerce_add_to_cart_direct`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L731) filter.

```
function so_30045089_redirect( $url ){

  $product_id          = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );

  if( $product_id == 999 ){
     $url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  }
  return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'so_30045089_redirect' );
```

Comment: not after but before adding to cart, needs to redirect to a page  then continue with configuration of the product depending on the designs you've made using FPD.

Comment: Ah ok. Well in that case why not use the [FPD plugin for WooCommerce](http://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-product-designer-woocommerce-plugin/6318393?ref=radykal) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the **woocommerce_add_cart_item_data** filter hook like this:

```
function your_function()
{
    // do your stuff here
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'your_function');
```

You would normally use filter hooks differently but since you are redirecting away from current request, you don't care about what would have happened next.